# Controlling LED results in flicking

Tags: pwm

Using the amazing Pi-Blaster daemon I managed to control a connected RGB strip (to be exact: this particular one http://www.ledstripkoning.nl/led-strips-rgb/losse-ledstrips-rgb/5-meter-150-leds-rgb-led-strip/ and [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2500356/10190897/00634d40-6770-11e5-88a1-9319024d3c75.JPG) in more detail).
The LED is driven by a 24V power supply and connected through [MOSFET's](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2500356/10190776/4986992e-676f-11e5-93c2-f524a621fb52.JPG). However, I'm experiencing a rather annoying problem: when setting any value (0,2 or 1 for example), the led is not giving a constant result. 
To illustrate, please see this small video: https://youtu.be/qEt5gFcJue4

I've also tried using the default PWM (hard and software),  which also results in (random) flickering.

Any thoughts on causes and possible solutions are highly appreciated; it's driving me nuts for days now.

Comment: Could you explain what you are actually sending to the RGB strip and the type of strip?  If possible include the script you are using in your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! Using the instructions on https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster I use the terminal command echo "18=1" > /dev/pi-blaster.

Comment: All that does is switch GPIO18 high (always on).  All that will do is switch a LED on or off (depending on how the LED was wired).

Comment: Exactly, that's the expected behavior. But instead I'm getting the result as seen in the video in the post started.

Comment: On the installation: we're using a 24V RGB LED strip. It's is wired identical to this: http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-pwm-rgb-led-strip/ (but instead of 12V we used a 24V power source).

Comment: There are dozens of different RGB LED strips with very different methods of being driven.  Without knowing what you actually have nobody can help.

Comment: I've added some links to pictures of the LED and MOSFET's (taken from https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster/issues/51).

Comment: Pictures don't tell us what we need to know, we need specific part numbers/datasheets

Comment: I already asked the seller of the LED-strip for the datasheet. Unfortunately he has to get those from the Chinese manufacturer, but due to holiday's there closed for a week. Hope to get the datasheet ASAP and will definitely post it here. Thanks for all the help so far!